# Cannot send Firebase Cloud Message from IBM Websphere Liberty Server to my Android Application

Tags: firebase-cloud-messaging, ssl-certificate, websphere-liberty

I am investigating Firebase Cloud Messaging in my current Android Application.

I have successfully integrated FCM into my Android application and used the Firebase console to send test messages.

I am now trying to develop my App Server to control messaging however its failing as follows:-

```
[ERROR   ] CWPKI0823E: SSL HANDSHAKE FAILURE:  A signer with SubjectDN [CN=upload.video.google.com, O=Google LLC, L=Mountain View, ST=California, C=US] was sent from the host [oauth2.googleapis.com:443].  The signer might need to be added to local trust store [/Users/josephDanielCasolaro /__NOTIFICATION/server/wlp/usr/servers/defaultServer/resources/security/key.p12], located in SSL configuration alias [defaultSSLConfig].  The extended error message from the SSL handshake exception is: [PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target].
```

my App server is running locally. The details are as follows:-

```
Launching defaultServer (WebSphere Application Server 20.0.0.4/wlp-1.0.39.cl200420200401-1714) on OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM, version 11.0.2+9 (en_GB)
```

My liberty profile server xml resembles this:-

```
<server description="new server">

    <!-- Enable features -->
    <featureManager>
        <feature>webProfile-8.0</feature>
        <feature>localConnector-1.0</feature>
    </featureManager>

    <!-- To access this server from a remote client add a host attribute to the following element, e.g. host="*" -->
    <httpEndpoint httpPort="9080" httpsPort="9443" id="defaultHttpEndpoint"/>

  <!-- Automatically expand WAR files and EAR files -->
    <applicationManager autoExpand="false"/>

    <keyStore id="defaultKeyStore" password="yourPassword"/>

    <applicationMonitor updateTrigger="mbean"/>
    <webTarget uri=""/>

    <webApplication id="Aardvarking" location="Aardvarking.war" name="Aardvarking"/>
</server>
```

My server code resembles:-

```
final InputStream serviceAccount = getClass().getClassLoader()
                .getResourceAsStream("/my-project.json");


        FirebaseOptions options = new FirebaseOptions.Builder()
                .setCredentials(GoogleCredentials.fromStream(serviceAccount))
                .setDatabaseUrl("https://my-project.firebaseio.com").build();

        FirebaseApp.initializeApp(options);


        // This registration token comes from the client FCM SDKs.
        final String registrationToken = "xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx";

        // See documentation on defining a message payload.
        final Message message = Message.builder().putData("score", "850").putData("time", "2:45").setToken(registrationToken)
                .build();

        // Send a message to the device corresponding to the provided
        // registration token.
        String response = FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().send(message);
        // Response is a message ID string.
        System.out.println("Successfully sent message: " + response);
```

Where have I gone wrong?

Is this a liberty profile server configuration issue?

Comment: I'm getting the same thing as you. not sure if you've been able to resolve this

Comment: @geofrey This must be a Liberty issue as I switched to using JBoss Wildfly19 server and it all worked fine